# Entropy of continuous and discrete random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, information-theory, entropy

If **N** is a *continuous* random variable and **X** a *discrete* random variable.

How can I calculate **H(X|Y)** if **Y=X+N**?

- **N** is a triangular distribution between -1 and 1
- **X** can take the values ​​+-0.5 with equal probability

*Assuming known:* H(X), h(N)=h(Y|X), h(Y) and pdf's of X, N and Y.

All the entropy terms are finite.

Comment: What exactly is denoted by $\mathbf{H(X\mid Y)}$?

Comment: The entropy of X conditioned on Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you shouldn't mix/confuse the "true" entropy with the differential entropy (differential entropy is not a true Shannon entropy). For one thing, the true entropy of a (non degenerate) continuous variable is infinite. But it's still true that the ("true") mutual information of any two random variables is well defined, using the difference of either true entropies or differential entropies (see for example [here](http://homepage.ntu.edu.tw/~ihwang/Teaching/Fa15/Slides/IT_Lecture_05_v0.pdf) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/360602/is-continuous-mutual-information-the-correct-analogue-of-the-discrete-version))

So, if $X$ is discrete and $Y$ continuous, we are justified in writing $I(X;Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)=h(Y)-h(Y|X)$ and hence

$$ H(X|Y) =   H(X) - I(X;Y)=H(X) -h(Y) + h(Y|X) $$

Comment: I understand what you say, but my teacher says we can not use:

$$H(X|Y)=H(X)-h(Y)+h(Y|X)$$

because we are mixing H with h. He says that we can only use it if both are discrete or both are continuous, and in my case X is discrete and Y continuous. 

That's why I do not know how to calculate $H(X|Y)$

Comment: No matter how you solve it, the end result will be just mine (and Gautam Shenoy's). So, in the end you will be "mixing H and h" (which are your only data). You cannot escape that. You only need to justify how to do it. And that I have mentioned (and linked to the details)

Answer (score 2):

From the mutual information relation
$$H(X|Y) = H(X) - h(Y) + h(Y|X)$$

Use this to get your desired result.

Comment: My teacher says that you can not mix entropies (H, discrete variables) with relative entropies (h, continuous variables)

Comment: Are all the entropy terms in your example finite?

Comment: Yes! All the entropy terms are finite.