# Calculating Capacity of a channel with mixture distribution.

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

Given a channel $Y=X+Z$ and a random variable $Z$ such that
$$
Z=\begin{cases}
0, &w.p. \frac{1}{10}\\
Z^* &w.p. \frac{9}{10}
\end{cases}
$$

such that $Z^* \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$

What is the capacity of the channel with power constraint $E[X^2] \le P$?

Since, $Z$ has a chance to send the message $X$ noiselessly, the capacity is infinite. But I am having difficulty explicitly calculating it.

Here is what I have tried:

We have,

$$
f_z(z) = \frac{1}{10}\delta(z) + \frac{9}{10}f_{z^*}(z)
$$

Assuming $Z$ is independent of $X$, the mutual information is

$$
I(X;Y) = h(Y) - h(Y|X)\\
=h(Y) - h(Z)
$$

Given that a Gaussian distribution maximizes entropy for a given variance,

$$
E[Z^2] = \int z^2 f_z(z) dz = \frac{9}{10}E[Z^{*2}] = \frac{9}{10} \sigma^2\\
E[Y^2] = E[X^2] + E[Z^2]\\
 \le P+\frac{9}{10}\sigma^2
$$

Then,

$$
I(X;Y) \le \frac{1}{2}\text{log}\bigg(1+\frac{P}{\frac{9}{10}\sigma^2}\bigg)
$$

I think I may have done something wrong, since it should be that $C=\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u r assuming $Z$ to be gaussian in the derivation but $Z$ is a mixed distribution. I am saying this because in ur final capacity upper bound u r assuming $h(Z)=\log(\frac{9 \sigma^2}{10})$ which is not true.
TO exactly calculate:
Let $U$ be a random variable which is $0$ is $Z=0$ or else $1$.
\begin{equation}
= C = I(X;Y) = h(Y)-h(Z) \\
= h(Y|U=0) 1/10 + h(Y|U=1) 9/10 + H(U)-H(U|Y) - ((h(Z|U=0) 1/10 + h(Z|U=1) 9/10)+H(U))\\
= (h(Y|U=0)-h(Z|U=0)) 1/10 + H(U)-H(U|Y) +  (h(Y|U=1)-h(Z|U=1)) 9/10 -H(U)\\
\geq (h(X)-h(Z|U=0)) 1/10  +  \log \left(1+\frac{P}{\sigma^2} \right) 9/10-H(U|Y)\\
\end{equation}
Here $h(Z|U=0) = -\infty$ (define it like this).
Hence u get the answer. 
Edited: We used $h(Y) = h(Y|U) + H(U) - H(U|Y)$, $h(Z,U) = H(U)+h(Z|U) = h(Z) + H(U|Z) = h(Z)$

Comment: Thanks. Here, why can we say that $h(Y) = h(Y|U) = \sum p(U=u) h(Y|U=u)$?

Comment: @Darklink9110 I Edited the answer. Thanks for the question.

Comment: @Darklink9110 Please see : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059820/entropy-of-continuous-and-discrete-random-variables